# How to Suppress Image Description Dialog in TinyMCE 3?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

We are using Tiny MCE 3 for a tool that is to be used for internal projects only so mandatory `alt` attribute on image tags is overkill.

When using the *Insert/Edit Image* dialogue, there is confirm dialogue (see below) that asks if you want to continue without an Image Description.

[image: TinyMCE Image Description Dialogue]

How do I suppress this dialogue so we can add images quicker (and dirtier)? I have had no luck with Google or the TinyMCE docs on this one.

Note this is for Tiny MCE 3.x, although we may migrate in the near future to 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things to change this...

**Configuration Setting `accessibility_warnings`:**

There is a setting you can put in the configuration that will turn off all accessibility warnings:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    accessibility_warnings : false
});
```

**Modify source code of `image.js` in the `advimage` plugin**

This file has code to check for the `alt` attribute.  In TinyMCE 3.5.10 I see this on line 104:

```
if (tinyMCEPopup.getParam("accessibility_warnings", 1)) {
  if (!f.alt.value) {                   
    tinyMCEPopup.confirm(tinyMCEPopup.getLang('advimage_dlg.missing_alt'),     
      function(s) {
        if (s)
          t.insertAndClose();
      });
    return;
  }
}
```

If you comment that out it won't check for the `alt` attribute anymore.  Of course you now have to re-do this change if you install an update to TinyMCE.

As a side note TinyMCE 3 is no longer getting any updates (I work for the company that owns TinyMCE).  It would be a really good idea to move to TinyMCE 4 (currently at 4.5.3) as that is the codebase that is getting enhancements at this point.

Comment: Looks to be exactly what I need. I'll accept once I've had a chance to test.